# AFNetworking 3.0 view log

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I used to use AFNetworkActivityLogger to print the network log, but I update AFNetworking to 3.0 recently, and AFNetworkActivityLogger not support 3.0.
So how could I print log like before when I am using AFNetworking 3.0?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using [`cocoapods`](https://cocoapods.org) add this line to your `Podfile` and run `pod install`

```
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', git: 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', branch: '3_0_0'
```

This will checkout the code from [branch `3_0_0`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/tree/3_0_0) of [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger).

I'd suggest you read through the [migration guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/tree/3_0_0#2x---3x-migration) because some of the methods in 2.x has been moved to other places.

Reference: [AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger#34](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/issues/34)

Answer (score 0):

`AFNetworkingLogger` now officially supports `AFNetworking 3.x`

Link - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/releases/tag/3.0.0

So I guess the right way would be

```
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', '3.0.0'
```